# Dealing with stubbed external dependency

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking, stub

In sut I should I have two kinds of dependencies to be stubbed: 3rd party dependencies (`mongodb` & co) and own dependencies:

```
var async = require('async'), // This dependency should not be stubbed
    mongodb = require('mongodb'), // 3rd party dependency, should be stubbed
    myOwnDependency = require('../my/ownDependency.js') // My own dependency, should be stubbed
```

In JS there are [3 possibilities two stub dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24225604/444079).

By the most of them (`rewire`, `sinon`) **all stubbed modules should *still physically installed* on dev machine**

I.e. I can not say: please load sut and do not load dependencies to be stubbed - do not execute `require` for `mondodb` and `ownDependency.js` - they are under my control.